# cannot assign a value in callback

Tags: java, android, callback

I refactoring code, and I want create factory with methods for work with server.
I have methot:

```
public DriverBadge updateDriverBadges() {
        DriverBadge driverBadge;
        try {
            ServerProxy.GetInstance().GetDriverBadge(new IRemoteCallback<DriverBadge>() {
                @Override
                public void Callback(Exception ex, DriverBadge badge) throws Exception {
        ...
                    driverBadge = badge;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return driverBadge;
    }
```

I want return object where receive to me from server in callback `DriverBadge badge` but I can not. `driverBadge = badge;` not work, because `driverBadge` not final and if it final idea say "cannot assign a value to final variable"

Answer (score 1):

#### Local reference can not be assigned in Inline Class.

If you want **driverBadge** assignable make it global .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign local reference in inline class.

If you want to use a local reference in inline class, then that reference should be `final`, which means it cannot be reassigned.

Besides, the logic of your code is wrong, `updateDriverBadges` may returns *before* the inline `IRemoteCallback` is called, such that it returns a reference which never be assigned.